# Need to Convert JsonString to Array in JQuery or Javascript VB.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, vb.net

I have json data which is returning from ajax post

Actual Json Data from Post

```json
{Status: 'True', Message: "['{"text":0.00, "value":"Bonnet", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Boot lid lock", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":3000.00, "value":"Front bumper", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1800.00, "value":"Front bumper bracket LH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1200.00, "value":"Front bumper grill clips", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":4000.00, "value":"Front bumper upper grill", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1000.00, "value":"Front wheel housing reinforcement LH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":3500.00, "value":"Rear tail lamp housing LH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":2500.00, "value":"Tail lamp LH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":2500.00, "value":"Tail lamp RH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Bonnet", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Bonnet Alu", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Bonnet hinge RH", "color": "#682437"}']"}
```

I did json.parse above response data like below code

```json
var dataObj = JSON.parse(response.d);
console.log(typeof dataObj)  // result as object
console.log(dataObj.Message)  // result as string
```

```
['{"text":0.00, "value":"Bonnet", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Boot lid lock", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":3000.00, "value":"Front bumper", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1800.00, "value":"Front bumper bracket LH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1200.00, "value":"Front bumper grill clips", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":4000.00, "value":"Front bumper upper grill", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1000.00, "value":"Front wheel housing reinforcement LH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":3500.00, "value":"Rear tail lamp housing LH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":2500.00, "value":"Tail lamp LH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":2500.00, "value":"Tail lamp RH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Bonnet", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Bonnet Alu", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Bonnet hinge RH", "color": "#682437"}']
```

now i want to split this dataObj.message to make it as array

like
text field as arText
value field as arValue
color field as arColor

After that i will populate these array to chart. so that the chart will be generating it.

I was trying to again json.parse data

```js
var data = JSON.parse(dataObj.Message);
//var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

I got below error message

```text
M742:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (Home.aspx:742:20)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2:27457)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:28202)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2:77651)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:79907)
    at Object.send (jquery.min.js:2:80266)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2:77118)
    at Function.s.ajax.s.ajax (jquery-migrate-3.3.2.min.js:2:3931)
    at fetchData (Home.aspx:724:5)
```

can you please help on this?
I tried some examples from stackoverflow. it did not work.

Comment: `['{"text":0.00, "value":"Bonnet", "color": "#682437"}', ... ,'{"text":1500.00, "value":"Bonnet hinge RH", "color": "#682437"}']` is not valid JSON. Try `JSON.parse(dataObj.message[0])`?

Comment: I verified json data online and good. I tried it but it's not working**` Unexpected end of Json Input at Json.parse **. Got this error.
Updated actual json data.

Comment: The problem is all the single quotes around each object in your dataObj.message. If you get rid of those then the json parses fine. Doesn't parse: `['{"text":0.00, "value":"Bonnet", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Boot lid lock", "color": "#682437"}','{"...`.  Does parse: `[{"text":0.00, "value":"Bonnet", "color": "#682437"},{"text":1500.00, "value":"Boot lid lock", "color": "#682437"},{"...`

Comment: Thanks @ourmandave. I have removed **single quote (')** from each objects. It's working...

Comment: Is the ‘JSON’ generated by a Python script by any chance?

Comment: @user3840170. no. VB.net

Answer (score 1):

as others have pointed out in the comments, your string is *NOT* valid json, but it's pretty close to valid json.. with some minor slice/split hacking, we can parse it:

```js
str=`{Status: 'True', Message: "['{"text":0.00, "value":"Bonnet", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Boot lid lock", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":3000.00, "value":"Front bumper", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1800.00, "value":"Front bumper bracket LH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1200.00, "value":"Front bumper grill clips", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":4000.00, "value":"Front bumper upper grill", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1000.00, "value":"Front wheel housing reinforcement LH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":3500.00, "value":"Rear tail lamp housing LH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":2500.00, "value":"Tail lamp LH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":2500.00, "value":"Tail lamp RH", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Bonnet", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Bonnet Alu", "color": "#682437"}','{"text":1500.00, "value":"Bonnet hinge RH", "color": "#682437"}']"}`;

arr = JSON.parse(str.split("Message: \"",2)[1].slice(0,-2).split("'").join(""))
```

works! :) ... it's very hack though, and ideally you should instead get the guy who wrote the json-generator to fix his json generator, it's broken, and it generates broken json.
[image]